# Running bash script from python

Tags: python, bash, sh

I'm encountering the following problem:

I have this simple script, called test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello() {
    echo "hello world"
}
hello
```

when I run it from shell, I got the expected result:

```
$ ./test2.sh
hello world
```

However, when I try to run it from Python (2.7.?) I get the following:

```
>>> import commands
>>> cmd="./test2.sh"
>>> commands.getoutput(cmd)
'./test2.sh: 3: ./test2.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'
```

I believe it somehow runs the script from "sh" rather than bash. I think so because when I run it with sh I get the same error message:

```
$ sh ./test2.sh
./test2.sh: 3: ./test2.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

In addition, when I run the command with preceding "bash" from python, it works:

```
>>> cmd="bash ./test2.sh"
>>> commands.getoutput(cmd)
'hello world'
```

My question is: Why does python choose to run the script with sh instead of bash though I added the `#!/bin/bash` line at the beginning of the script? How can I make it right (I don't want to use preceding 'bash' in python since my script is being run from python by distant machines which I cant control).

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, your shebang looks all wrong. `#~/bin/bash`, this isn't even a shebang but a simple comment. It should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Sorry. Was just a typo

Comment: It works unaltered on my Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit. May be something with your default environment that is causing sh to be used instead of bash.

Comment: try os.system() it works

Comment: Oh I see, that's very strange then. What distribution are you using there?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some other problem - the shbang and commands.getoutput should work properly as you show here. Change the shell script to just:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 100
```

and run the app again. Check with `ps f` what's the actual process tree. It's true that getoutput calls `sh -c ...`, but this shouldn't change which shell executes the script itself.

From a minimal test as described in the question, I see the following process tree:

```
11500 pts/5    Ss     0:00 zsh
15983 pts/5    S+     0:00  \_ python2 ./c.py
15984 pts/5    S+     0:00      \_ sh -c { ./c.sh; } 2>&1
15985 pts/5    S+     0:00          \_ /bin/bash ./c.sh
15986 pts/5    S+     0:00              \_ sleep 100
```

So in isolation, this works as expected - python calls `sh -c { ./c.sh; }` which is executed by the shell specified in the first line (bash).

Make sure you're executing the right script - since you're using `./test2.sh`, double-check you're in the right directory and executing the right file. (Does `print open('./test2.sh').read()` return what you expect?)